# Is there a simple test in Bash to test if a logical path is a directory

Tags: testing, directory, exists

The question is best explained through a small example:

Create an infrastructure of directories as follows:

```
rm -rf /tmp/work  
mkdir -p /tmp/work/a/b/c  
cd /tmp/work  
ln -s a/b/c s  
mkdir t  
tree
```

This results in the following infrastructure:

[image: Directory infrastructure]

There is a very simple way to check for the existence of a directory:

```
cd /tmp/work
if test -d s/../t; then echo EXISTS; else echo DOES NOT EXIST; fi
```

[image: Directory test]

However, it seems that the '-d' test only checks for the physical path (`a/b/t`); The following clearly shows that the logical path/directory **does** exist:

```
cd s/../t
pwd
```

[image: Logical path]

I am hoping for a simple test to get this situation checked...
Checking for similar questions in StackOverflow, I haven't found an answer that differentiates logical paths from physical paths...

I did a brute force (silly) attempt to get some more insight:

```
for o in -b -c -d -e -f -g -G -k -h -L -O -p -r -S -s -t -u -w -x; do
  if test $o s/../t; then echo EXISTS; else echo DOES NOT EXIST; fi
done
```

As expected, all of the tests indicate failure...

Answer (score 0):

The closest I get to a simple solution is the following test:

```
if (unset CDPATH; cd -L s/../t &>/dev/null); then echo EXISTS; else echo DOES NOT EXIST; fi
```

If using '-P' rather than '-L', then this syntax tests for physical paths (the equivalent of 'test -d').

Note that if we're sure that we're using builtins, then the syntax is just a bit simpler:

```
if (unset CDPATH; cd s/../t &>/dev/null); then echo EXISTS; else echo DOES NOT EXIST; fi
```

But there must be a better way...